# How to sort by Datetime in Mulesoft Dataweave?

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-platform

How do I sort and array of json that needs sorting by date using Dataweave 2

```
{
 "things": [
  {
    "datetime": "2020-11-07T16:11:52.866Z",
    "name": "foo"
  },
  {
    "datetime": "2020-11-07T16:11:39.971Z",
    "name": "bar"
  },
  {
    "datetime": "2020-11-07T16:11:39.978Z",
    "name": "baz"
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: The input is invalid. It is missing the curly brackets around the object. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `orderBy` function

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
orderedDates: (payload.things orderBy $.datetime)
```

By default the output is in ascending order.

If you need descending you can do this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
orderedDates: (payload.things orderBy $.datetime)[-1 to 0]
```

Also you can use datetime formatting if you get inputs with different timezones. With your current input values you can use `LocalDateTime`

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
orderedDates: (payload.things orderBy ($.datetime as LocalDateTime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"}))
```

Comment: THis seems to break on 2021-01-25T12:57:48.2Z - but not on 2021-01-25T12:57:48.20Z or 2021-01-25T12:57:48.200Z - and also if the breaking string is the only one in the list then that's ok

Answer (score 1):

Just use orderBy() and select the field with the date-time.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.things orderBy ((item, index) -> item.datetime)
```